# Is here a way iterate recursively on java bean in freemarker

Tags: java, jsp-tags, freemarker

Is here a way to iterate recursively on java bean in freemarker like print_t() or var_dump() in php. I know freemarker also supports jsp taglibs, so may be I should look this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such functionality built in (yet?). For now the best one can do is writing a custom directive for it (see `TemplateDirectiveModel`), but it's not trivial to write a such directive that works well in all situations, because of the abstraction layer (object wrapping) FreeMarker introduces between the actual Java objects and what the template sees from them. But writing one that's good enough for a specific projects should not be difficult.